# void* to UnicodeString in driver

Tags: c++, string, winapi, unicode, driver

Sorry if this is a really dumb question but here goes.

I recently got into C++ and I have to modify a driver for a project I am working on. The problem is that my driver needs to take a string I'm storing in a `void*`.  So basically, my question is, how can I cast this, or do this, in a very simple way?

```cpp
void get_modulebase(int pid, void* value, void* data) {
    PEPROCESS t_process;
    UNICODE_STRING mod;
    KAPC_STATE apc;
    DbgPrint("Data: %s \n", data); //this prints the string as i need it

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&mod, (PCWSTR)data); //this fails

    PsLookupProcessByProcessId((HANDLE)pid, &t_process);
    PVOID base_address = BBGetUserModule(t_process, &mod);
    KeUnstackDetachProcess(&apc);
    RtlCopyMemory(value, &base_address, 8);
    ObfDereferenceObject(t_process);
}
```

This works for me, but I need to store the module name into `data`:

```cpp
RtlInitUnicodeString(&mod, L"notepad.exe");
```

Comment: if you use "%s" format in `DbgPrint` for `data` this mean that data point to ansi string. `RtlInitUnicodeString` require wide char string. so you need first convert ansi to unicode say by `RtlMultiByteToUnicodeN`

Comment: Im trying to make this work but having a lot of difficulty.
could you show me the correct way ?
RtlMultiByteToUnicodeN((PWCH)&mod, datasize, (PULONG)datasize, static_cast<const char*>(data), datasize);

Answer (score 0):

[RtlInitUnicodeString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-rtlinitunicodestring) is one of the few unsafe string calls left that Windows does not flag.

Refer: [char* ( char pointer) and RtlInitUnicodeString() function](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/fb811a06-79c1-4a5b-b41f-3f96f7944ec3/char-char-pointer-and-rtlinitunicodestring-function?forum=wdk)

I suggest that you can use `RTL_CONSTANT_STRING` macro in wdk which can be used to create UNICODE_STRING in compile time.

Like this:

```
static const UNICODE_STRING foo = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"notepad.exe");
```

Comment: @Chris Doe Hi, does this answer help you?